# How to Count id which id have have values other column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
ID     Diagnosis   
---------------
1       d1
1       d2
1       d3         
2       d1
2       d3
2       d4
3       d1
3       d2
```

I want to count the unique `ID`s that have both `d1`and `d2`.

Desired Output Like this

```
total    
------
2
```

How can write SQL Code to achieve this?

Comment: MySQL or MSSQL.It doesnt matter.

Comment: uncleared how the count comes 2?? can you explain it??

Comment: count of id which have d1 and d2

Answer (score 2):

You could use a couple of `in` conditions:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM   my_table
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE diagnosis = 'id1') AND
       id IN (SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE diagnosis = 'id2')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution for MySQL...

```
SELECT x.id 
  FROM my_table x 
 WHERE diagnosis IN ('d1','d2') 
 GROUP 
    BY id 
HAVING COUNT(*) =2;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  3 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec) <-- ANSWER!!!
```

Comment: +1 - Nice solution. This implicitly assumes that the combination of `[id, diagnosis]` is unique (otherwise, two rows of `[1, d1]` would also return the row, although its not intended. I'm guessing this is a sound assumption, although OP doesn't explicitly state that.

Comment: @Mureinik Yes, in fact I assumed a PK on (id,diagnosis). If this wasn't the case then COUNT(DISTINCT) would achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.. I've updated it..

```
select count(*) as TOTAL from TABLE_NAME where Diagnosis in ('d1', 'd2') group by Diagnosis
```

Comment: This isn't correct - it will also count `id`s that have just `d1` or just `d2`

Comment: This cant help me.Because in expression means d1 or d2.But I want to d1 and d2

Comment: @tcett: So You want count for d1 and d2 seperete ?

Comment: No , d1 and d2 must exist.Not seperate

Answer (score 0):

you have written your question very vaguely but I think you want below solution in MSSQL:

```
select COUNT(1) from 
(
    select distinct(id) from my_table where Diagnosis = 'd1'
    intersect
    select distinct(id) from my_table where Diagnosis = 'd2'
) as TempResultset
```

If you run inner query alone, you will get the Ids.

Comment: apologies, I have created this script from my sql server and can't show you for some reason and I don't know SQLFiddle.